# Select all sheets except two

Tags: excel, vba

I need to select all sheets (number and sheet names will vary) in a workbook except two sheets named "Overview" and "Index" (which also happen to be the left-most sheets on the tab list).

Is there "generic" code that can do this without naming each sheet (other than the two sheets that I do not want selected)?

I tried the following code to see if I could select all sheets except one:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
Dim i As Long
Sheet1.Select
For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    If Sheets(i).Name <> "Overview" Then Sheets(i).Select Replace:=False
Next i
End Sub
```

I get:

> run-time error '1004

When I click debug, it highlights the `Sheet1.Select` line.

Comment: Most often, there is no need to select anything, especially a bunch of worksheets. There is a short list of things you can do with these worksheets at the same time e.g. copy, move, or delete. What are you planning to do with them?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    Dim iSel As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, _
                   Array("Overview", "Index"), 0)) Then
            ws.Select Replace:=(iSel = 0) 'only Replace for first-selected sheet 
            iSel = iSel + 1 'increment selected sheet count
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

(assumes no hidden sheets)

Comment: Ah Tim, yours is so much more elegant... as per usual. I'm keeping my answer up though, as it provides the hidden sheet checking.
I knew you could match an array like that, but i never though to do so in this way. I considered looping an array to allow the user to add or remove workbooks to ignore, but it seemed like too many lines,

Comment: @CameronCritchlow - your is more complete I think...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option.

```
Sub SelectWS()
    
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim I As Long
    Dim N As Long
    Dim Fnd As Boolean
    Dim Vis As Boolean
    
    N = 0
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        Vis = (WS.Visible = xlSheetVisible)
        If Vis = False Then N = N + 1
        
        If WS.Name <> "Overview" And WS.Name <> "Index" And Vis Then
            Fnd = True
            If ActiveSheet.Name = "Overview" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Index" Then
                WS.Activate
                WS.Select
            Else
                WS.Select (False)
            End If
        End If
    Next WS
    
    If Not Fnd Then
        MsgBox "No suitable WS found.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Error:"
    ElseIf N > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Found " & N & " hidden Worksheet(s) - not selectable.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Notice:"
    End If
    
End Sub
```